# Import laravel 4.2 project into eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel, laravel-4, eclipse-luna

I have installed `laravel 4.2` via `composer` and created in the `htdocs folder` of my `xampp` installation a new project. When I enter `localhost` everything runs perfectly fine.

Now I would like to import this project into `eclipse luna`. I have alredy installed the pdt plugin under eclipse. However, how to import the laravel project, for further development?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Go to File > Import

[image]

2. Existing folder as New Project

[image]

3. Find the folder and click Finish
   [image]

Comment: You might want to check also this: http://www.codeforest.net/laravel-4-tips-resourses