# Import laravel 4.2 project into eclipse not working

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I followed the post *[Import laravel 4.2 project into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201029/import-laravel-4-2-project-into-eclipse)* to import the Laravel project into Eclipse

1. This is my project location:
   [image]
2. This is the import dialog:
   [image]

I was searching for option **"Existing Folder as New Project"**, but I could not find.

I created new PHP project and tried following options also to import it:

1. Existing project into workspace
2. FileSystem
3. Projects from folder or Archive

In these options going next step, the Laravel project is not listing in project directory and project is not importing.

Is the options is replacable, which one is correct and relevant option?

Comment: Because it is not an Eclipse project (e. g. the `.project` file is missing), use _File > Open Projects from File System..._ (shortcut for _File > Import...: General > Projects from Folder or Archive_). It will be imported as a new project and if the _PHP Project_ detector detects it, it will also be configure as a PHP project. Use the latest version of Eclipse for better detection.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Great. I've added an answer how you can also have the history of the project. With the history you can for example right-click the left editor ruler and choose _Show Revision Information_ (= Git blame) for information on why a line was last edited or added.

Answer (score 2):

The import wizards *Existing Projects into Workspace* and *File System* work only for Eclipse projects. [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) is not shared as an Eclipse project (e. g. the `.project` file is missing).

Instead of downloading it and to have the history, all you have to do is (requires at least Eclipse Oxygen):

1. **Drag** the [Laravel **GitHub website URL**](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) **onto your Eclipse IDE** to clone the Git repository ([like shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=505s))
2. In the ***Git Repository*** view **right-click the *Working Tree*** node and choose ***Import Projects...*** to import it as a new project

For already downloaded projects:

1. With the Windows *Explorer* (outside of Eclipse) move or copy it to the location where you want to edit it (e. g. into your Eclipse workspace)
2. In Eclipse open the project directory via *File > Open Projects from File System...*

Note, use the latest version of Eclipse for better detection of non-Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by following steps

1.Create Separate workSpace

2.Add my Laravel Project folder into that workspace folder

3.File > Import...: General > Projects from Folder or Archive and select location

Comment: Comment those lines below at @howlger answer ...not as an answer.